# Get full JSON response from Sonarqube Web API

Tags: sonarqube

I am using Sonarqube web API to detect bugs in [spoon](https://sonarqube.ow2.org/project/issues?id=fr.inria.gforge.spoon%3Aspoon-core&resolved=false&types=BUG). But I'm not getting the full list of about 189 bugs, but only about 100 even when I used types=BUG parameter. The GET request I'm using is https://sonarqube.ow2.org/api/issues/search?componentKeys=fr.inria.gforge.spoon:spoon-core&types=BUG . Is there any way to get the full JSON response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get only 100 items as 100 is the default pagesize for Web api pagination.
In your example when using:

```
https://sonarqube.ow2.org/api/issues/search?componentKeys=fr.inria.gforge.spoon:spoon-core&types=BUG&ps=200
```

you'll get all 189 bugs. The max value for pagesize is 500.
If you want to know the total count for issues you'll need to check the response:

```
{
  "paging": {
    "pageIndex": 1,
    "pageSize": 100,
    "total": 189 <<---------------------------
  },
  "issues": [
    {
...
```

A groovy snippet using total to get all issues with looping:

```
import groovy.json.*

def sonarRest(url,method) {
  jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
  raw = '...:'
  bauth = 'Basic ' + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(raw.getBytes())
  conn = new URL(url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
  conn.setRequestMethod(method)
  conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", bauth)
  conn.connect()
  httpstatus = conn.responseCode
  object = jsonSlurper.parse(conn.content)
}

issues = sonarRest('https://sonarhost/api/issues/search?severities=INFO&ps=1', 'GET')
total = (issues.total.toFloat()/100).round()

counter = 1

while(counter <= total)
{
issues = sonarRest("https://sonarhost/api/issues/search?severities=INFO&ps=100&p=$counter", 'GET')
println issues
counter++
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rebse. Maybe you can also help me with this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50697098/junit-test-for-sonarube-repair](question) related to sonarqube.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't even need it. I can add rule to the parameter since I'm only using one rule at a time.